get total of empty values in an object
please I need help with this
const obj = {a="", b="good", c=false, d="", e="excellent"}

I just want to know total empty and false. where my answer is suppose to be 3.
const obj = {a="", b="good", c=false, d="", e="excellent"}

for (let k in obj) {
  if (obj[k] === '' || obj[k] === false) {
    //console.log(k);

  }
}

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated
THank you

You need to fix the syntax of your object literal.    Then you need to add a counter that gets incremented where your console.log() call is.

What you're showing isn't valid JS. But if you did have valid JS, a good place to start would be Object.values(obj).reduce(...) (or if you also want to do something with the key names, Object.entries instead of Object.values)

You can reduce over Object.values.


const obj = {a: "", b: "good", c: false, d: "", e: "excellent"};
let falsyValuesCount = Object.values(obj).reduce((a, c) => a + !c, 0);
console.log(falsyValuesCount);



To get the actual values that were falsy, use Array#filter instead.

Here's a one liner to archieve your result set using Array.Prototype.filter :


const obj = {a: "", b: "good", c: false, d: "", e: "excellent"};

const resultArray = Object.values(obj).filter(value => value === '' || value === false);

console.log("Count :", resultArray.length); 
console.log("Array values :", JSON.stringify(resultArray));




Read more on Array.Prototype.filter operation here


You could just make an array and put the keys that are empty into it. That way, at the end of the program, the length of the array will be the number of empty elements.
const obj = {a:"", b:"good", c:false, d:"", e:"excellent"}
const emptyElements = [] // an array containing all the keys of the properties that are empty
for (let key in obj) {
  if (obj[key] === '' || obj[key] === false) {
    // Key is empty
    emptyElements.push(k)
  }
}
console.log(emptyElements.length) // the number of empty elements in the object

Or you could simply add a variable that increments whenever it finds an empty value.
const obj = {a:"", b:"good", c:false, d:"", e:"excellent"}
let nEmptyElements = 0 // Number of empty elements
for (let key in obj) {
  if (obj[key] === '' || obj[key] === false) {
    // Key is empty
    nEmptyElements += 1 // Increment the number of empty element
  }
}
console.log(nEmptyElements) // the number of empty elements in the object

Hope this helps



const obj = {a:"", b:"good", c:false, d:"", e:"excellent"};

let count = 0; 

for (let k in obj) {
  if (obj[k] === '' || obj[k] === false) {
    count++; 
  }
}

console.log(count); 



